# Some keys toggle other keys on my laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard

When typing certain letters, other letters/symbols are also appearing. The letters in my case are:

P " 
Q = 
D <

and sometimes a "right control" is triggered. So when I'm typing P, the " symbol is appearing too and when pressing ", the P appears (likewise with the other 2 "couples").

I've registered this behavior by using a thrid party tool that indicate the pressed letters on a virtual keyboard. When connecting a USB keyboard, all letters are typed in correctly: typing P only shows a P (without the "). This makes me believe that it isn't a software issue but rather hardware malfunction (keyboard connector damaged inside the laptop).

Does anyone have experience with these symptoms and can recommend me more troubleshooting options or solutions?

The laptop is a Sony Vaio VPC-EB3L1E, out of warranty and running Win 7 Home premium.

Comment: I think you've worked out the issue your self with your own diagnosis really. I'm not sure how we can answer this further to what you've already found.

Comment: @DaveRook: I'm not sure my diagnosis is right. This is the first time I'm encountering this problem. MAybe someone else recognizes this and can share his/her solution.

Comment: It would be nice to see what's wrong with a question if people downvote, so I can either adjust it or keep the feedback in mind for future problems.

Answer (score 1):

> This makes me believe that it isn't a software issue but rather hardware malfunction

Well, time to test your theory then.

Boot from a [LiveCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD); does it behave the same way in that 3rd party OS?  Yes?  Then it's a hardware issue, replace the keyboard with a known good one.

If you suspect a busted connector, check those over while you're in there, perhaps before buying a replacement keyboard.